# Hosting MVC2 on IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I need a little help. I'm trying to host an MVC 2 application on IIS6. On my dev machine (XP) it runs perfectly in Cassini or as web site in IIS.

First i tried to reference the .mvc extension to aspnet_isapi but when that didn't work i went with the aspx extension instead.

Any ideas? I've probably missed something obvious.

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = ""} // Parameter defaults
                );
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Root",
                "",
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = ""}
                );
        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

Had some bad references that i cleaned out and is now stuck with this on my master page:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have asp.net mvc2 installed on the target computer?

Comment: Yes, I performed the installation myself.

Comment: Found the error, it was in the installation script...i feel very ashamed. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should try this:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Does your .aspx mapping in IIS (or your failed .mvc mapping) have the "check that file exists" option ticked?

That's the most obvious first place it can fail. Also, when the .mvc mapping failed, was it the same error or different (realise that this latter sentence may have been better as a comment...)

Comment: Neither of the mappings have that checked unfortunately.