# Deploy .net MVC 2 application on IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes, iis-6

I want to deploy my .net MVC 2 application on IIS6.0. 
Will it require to change route path in global.asax file.

In my application i have used html link, ajax request and Html.ActionLink.

The code lines in the Global.asax file are:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "LogOn", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

MVC2 works just fine in IIS6, though there are some gotchas with the 4.0 framework. Your routes won't be a problem, but you'll have to add a wildcard map for aspnet_isapi.dll to enable extensionless URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see a reason why it won't work. The routes don't need to be setup differently if you intend to deploy to IIS6.

The best way to find out is to try it ;)

Comment: Michael I diployed the application on IIS6.0 and tryed to access by http://myip/Account and http://myip/Account/index then i got the 404 error. For this i installed mvc 2 framework on the server. So is there any settings regarding mvc on IIS 6.0 those are needed ?

Comment: Do either http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160838/hosting-mvc2-on-iis6 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642403/asp-net-4-0-mvc2-routing-on-iis-6 help?

Answer (score 0):

I just put in an extension to tell iis to use the asp_net.dll.  My urls aren't as pretty, but they work.  i.e. they are like http://example.com/Home.aspx/ActionName/Id

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "root", // Route name
    "", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```